# How could/should I state colon (punctuation) in a YAML file?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, yaml

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.1.0 and I would like to know *how to correctly state colon (punctuation) in a YAML file*. I tried to support that by adding the following code in my `config/locales/defaults/en.yml file`

```
en
  # '&#58;' is the HTML code for ':'
  test_key_html: Test value&#58;
```

and in my view file I used

```
t('test_key_html')
```

but it doesn't work (in the front end content is displayed the "plain" `Test value&#58;` text).

**Is it possible? If so how?**

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You should be able to double quote the value:

```
test_key_html: "Test value:"
```

This avoids colon-confusion in the YAML and gets your colon into your HTML.

Consider this in `irb`:

```
>> { 'en' => { 'test_key_html' => 'Test value:' } }.to_yaml
=> "--- \nen: \n  test_key_html: "Test value:"\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
raw(t('test_key_html'))
```

Rails 3+ automattically escapes html markup