# Escaping colons in YAML

Tags: escaping, yaml, delimiter

Does anyone know how to escape colons in YAML?  The key in my yml is the
domain with port number, but the yml file isn't working with this setup:

```
###BEGIN
production:
### THIS IS THE ONE I'm HAVING TROUBLE WITH ###
8.11.32.120:8000: GoogleMapsKeyforThisDomain
exampledomain.com: GoogleMapsAPIKeyforThatDomain

development:
 GoogleMapsAPIKeyforDevelopmentDomain
###END
```

I'm using a google maps plugin called YM4R that uses a .yml file to
select the different Google Maps API key depending on where my app is
being hosted...

So, I'm trying to make `8.11.32.120:8000 the key`.  Any idea how to do
this?  (It's in the gmaps_api_key.yml file if you care)

Comment: Does double-quoting the whole string (ie: `"8.11.32.120:8000: GoogleMapsKeyforThisDomain"`) work as per [this StackOverflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11301650/567863)?

Comment: WOrks with quotes, are you telling me that is the only way to escape it?

Comment: There's info out there about [using double-quotes to escape colons in values](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8783705/567863), but I haven't seen anything specifically to do with escaping colons in keys apart from [a Ruby Forum post where this same question was asked back in 2007](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/127343), where the advice there was also to just double-quote the key.  So, I guess you can either go with double quoting just the key, or both the key and value.

Comment: I saw that post and just wanted any other ways to do it.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You'll need to put quotes around the key you're having trouble with. I.e.:

```
"8.11.32.120:8000": GoogleMapsKeyforThisDomain
```

Comment: WOrks with quotes, can't we do it any other way?

Comment: I haven't come across any other way of doing it, sorry.

Comment: I've had success with HTML entities (e.g. "&colon;")

Comment: Just out of curiosity: **Why** would you want another way?

Comment: Because this doesn't work: `- sed -i "s/driver: .*/driver: pdo_$DB/" etc/config.yaml`

Answer (score 11):

To answer a comment another way for list items like:

```
- sed -i "s/driver: .*/driver: pdo_$DB/" etc/config.yaml
```

is to write them as:

```
- >-
  sed -i "s/driver: .*/driver: pdo_$DB/" etc/config.yaml
```

or as:

```
- 'sed -i "s/driver: .*/driver: pdo_$DB/" etc/config.yaml'
```

Comment: For those who are wondering like I was: the `>` indicates a folded scalar, which means that characters that are otherwise special yaml characters are not interpreted. The `-` is a chomp control modifier, indicating that eventual newlines in a `>` block should be stripped.